# Is it possible to make Wordpress as a RESTful app?

Tags: plugin-development, json, curl, rest-api

I'm planning to create a Wordpress plugin that accepts data via cURL and sends a JSON reply. The plugin will save the data in the database upon receive so there has to be some authentication and will send JSON data back as a confirmation if data is successfully saved. Is it possible?

Comment: it is indeed possible, in fact [someone is already doing it](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/06/17/json-rest-api/).

Comment: So there's no official support for it? And that would mean it can't be done via WP API or something?

Comment: Jetpack/WordPress.com also have a JSON API. http://jetpack.me/support/json-api/